How to wrap long texts vertically within a table
I have a table with very long texts as column headings. This is causing the table to stretch too much horizontally. I want to break the texts vertically within each cell.
Find below a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
....
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering  
\resizebox{\textwidth{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
      & (1)   & (2) \\
      & xxxxxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      & yyyyyyyyyyy: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\\
}
 \end{table}
\end{document}

I want it to look something like this:
example table
I have tried the following:

using multirow
breaking the title like below

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
....
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering  
\resizebox{\textwidth{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
      & (1)   & (2) \\
      & {xxxxxxxxxxx: \\ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
      & {yyyyyyyyyyy: \\ yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\\
}
 \end{table}
\end{document}


Both of these push the second part of the title to the far left column.
Appreciate any help!

\multicolumn{1}{p{<width>}{my long heading for this column}? Scaling tables is considered a Typographical Evil of the First Degree ;).

You have lot of options in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options
